# How to draw three-dimensional image: Plot3D NDSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
m = 10; c = 2; k = 5; F = 12;

NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t] == F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t], 
         x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

> {f, 0, 5}   ( 0=< f <= 5 )

How to draw three-dimensional image:

> x = u(t,f)

............

If f = 0.1,0.2,... 5, 
We can solve the equation:

```
NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t] == F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t], 
         x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

x is a function of t and f

...............

```
m = 10; c = 2; k = 5; F = 12;

f = 0.1

s = NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t] == F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t], 
             x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 30}] 
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

f = 0.1
[image]

f = 0.2
[image]

f = 0.3
[image]

f = 5
[image]

How to draw three-dimensional image:
x = u(t,f)

Comment: I attempted to fix the formatting in your question.  Please tell me if that is what you intended.  Also, I really don't understand your question.  Would you please try to clarify it?

Comment: Trying the given code gives the error message `NDSolve::nlnum: "The function value {0.,1/10\ (0.\[VeryThinSpace]+12\ Sin[0.0193488\ f])}\\n is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} at \!\({t, x[t], \*SuperscriptBox[\"x\", \"\[Prime]\",MultilineFunction->None][t]}\) = {0.00307945,0.,0.}."` — should that have been an uppercase F in the sine?

Comment: m = 10;
c = 2;
k = 5;
F = 12;

If f = 0.1,0.2,... 5, We can solve the equation:
NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t] == F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], {t, 0, 30}] 

x is a function of t and f

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here goes a solution.

```
m = 10; c = 2; k = 5; F = 12;
NumberOfDiscrit$f = 20;(* Number of points you want to divide 0<=f<=5*)
NumberOfDiscrit$t = 100;(* Number of points you want to divide 0<=t<=30 *)
fValues = Range[0., 5., 5./(NumberOfDiscrit$f - 1)];
tValues = Range[0., 30., 30./(NumberOfDiscrit$t - 1)];
res = Map[(x /. 
  First@First@
    NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*#*t])*x[t] == 
       F*Sin[2*Pi*#*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 30}]) &,
fValues];
AllDat = Map[(#@tValues) &, res];
InterpolationDat = 
Flatten[Table[
Transpose@{tValues, 
  Table[fValues[[j]], {i, 1, NumberOfDiscrit$t}], 
  AllDat[[j]]}, {j, 1, NumberOfDiscrit$f}], 1];
Final3DFunction = Interpolation[InterpolationDat];
Plot3D[Final3DFunction[t, f], {t, 0, 30}, {f, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All,
PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 3, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

You can use `Manipulate` to dynamically change some of the parameters. By the way the above 3D picture may be misleading if one takes `f` as a continuous variable in `u(t,f)`. You should note that the numerical solution seems to blow up for asymptotic values of `t>>30`. See the picture below.

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 6):

You could also do something like this

```
Clear[f]
m = 10; c = 2; k = 5; F = 12;

s = NDSolve[{m*Derivative[2, 0][x][t, f] + 
     c*Derivative[1, 0][x][t, f] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t, f] == F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t],
   x[0, f] == 0,
   Derivative[1, 0][x][0, f] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 30}, {f, 0, .2}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[x[t, f] /. s[[1]]], {t, 0, 30}, {f, 0, .2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: I tried to figure this out myself, but I gave up.  I knew it had to be possible.  Big +1.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried to do like this way, but I gave up.
Because I do not know to write this expression:
Derivative[1, 0][x][0, f] == 0

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
m = 10; c = 2; k = 5; F = 12;


fun[f_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[
   {x, t}, 
   First[x /. 
     NDSolve[
      {m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t] == F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t],
       x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
      x, {t, 0, 30}
     ]
   ]
 ]

ContourPlot[fun[f][t], {f, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

Important points:

- The pattern _?NumericQ prevents `fun` from being evaluated for symbolc arguments (think `fun[a]`), and causing `NDSolve::nlnum` errors.
- Since `NDSolve` doesn't appear to localize its function variable (`t`), we needed to do this manually using `Module` to prevent conflict between the `t` used in `NDSolve` and the one used in `ContourPlot`.  (You could use a differently named variable in `ContourPlot`, but I think it was important to point out this caveat.)

---

For a significant speedup in plotting, you can use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), as pointed out by Mr. Wizard.

```
Clear[funMemo] (* very important!! *)

funMemo[f_?NumericQ] := 
 funMemo[f] = Module[{x, t}, 
   First[x /. 
     NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + (k*Sin[2*Pi*f*t])*x[t] == 
        F*Sin[2*Pi*f*t], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 30}]]]

ContourPlot[funMemo[f][t], {f, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 30}] (* much faster than with fun *)
```

---

If you're feeling adventurous, and willing to explore Mathematica a bit more deeply, you can further improve this by limiting the amount of memory the cached definitions are allowed to use, [as I described here](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php).

Let's define a helper function for enabling memoization:

```
SetAttributes[memo, HoldAll]
SetAttributes[memoStore, HoldFirst]
SetAttributes[memoVals, HoldFirst]

memoVals[_] = {};

memoStore[f_, x_] := 
 With[{vals = memoVals[f]}, 
  If[Length[vals] > 100, f /: memoStore[f, First[vals]] =.;
   memoVals[f] ^= Append[Rest[memoVals[f]], x], 
   memoVals[f] ^= Append[memoVals[f], x]];
  f /: memoStore[f, x] = f[x]]

memo[f_Symbol][x_?NumericQ] := memoStore[f, x]
```

Then using the original, non-memoized `fun` function, plot as

```
ContourPlot[memo[fun][f][t], {f, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good point. I added memory-constrained memoization as well.

Comment: Nice.  Now I am happy. +1 ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I think in the `ContourPlot` you must have `memo[funMemo][f][t]`. Right?

Comment: @PlatoManiac No, it's just `memo[fun][f][t]`.  The `memo` function takes care of memoization, you don't have to do it manually like in `funMemo`.  Since `memo` has to be written only once (unlike manual memoization), we can afford to do complicated things in it, like limit the number of values it remembers.  I wrote this code many years ago and haven't tested it that much, so you should be careful with it (but I haven't found any problems myself).

Comment: @Szabolcs You are right I just did not see the Clear[fun] before so when evaluated `memo[fun][f][t]` my `ContourPlot` gave no picture :). Sorry!

Comment: @PlatoManiac Oops, that should be `Clear[funMemo]`!! Thanks for catching that

Comment: @Szabolcs good luck getting one.  My bet is on user seeing the failure that I had, but the user never coming back to see the fix. :-(

Comment: By the way, didn't you post a question about sparse array formats a little while ago?  I cannot find it now.